# Why is pre_get_posts hook invoked multiple times?

Tags: hooks, pre-get-posts

I am using `pre_get_posts` hook, however as it is not working as expected, I have discovered that the function is being invoked 4 times, and while the first call is running as expected, subsequent calls will not run correctly.
I wonder why my custom hook is being run more than once!

I have found an [article that explains why this may happen](https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-hooks-firing-twice/), but I am confused as in my case this shouldn't happen at all....

Code:

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    global $acorn_user;
    $tax_query = array();

    if ( $query->is_feed ) {
        /**** Exclude "exclude" category posts from feed ********/
        $query->set('cat', '-617, -618');
        return $query;
    }

    $args = array(
        'category__not_in' => 2 ,
        'category__in' =>  22,
        'posts_per_page' => 7,
        'post_status' => 'publish');

    if (!is_user_logged_in()  /*&& !is_admin()*/) {
        /**** Exclude child categories ********/
        if ($query->is_category(3) || $query->is_category(68) || $query->is_category(69) || $query->is_category(70)) {
            $queried_object = get_queried_object();
            $child_cats = (array)get_term_children($queried_object->term_id, 'category');

            if (!$query->is_admin) {
                //exclude the posts in child categories
                $tax_query[] = array('category__not_in', array(68, 69, 70, 81, 82, 83));
            }
        }
    }
    //exclude search results for parents & teachers & non logged users
    if ( $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if(empty($acorn_user) || !in_array( 'teacher', (array) $acorn_user->roles )) {
            $tax_query[] = array('post__not_in', array(30140, 30020, 30008, 29998, 29991, 21458,20197,11986,6614));
        }
    }
    if (!empty($tax_query)) {
        $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Comment: pre_get_posts runs any time posts are queried. This includes the main list of posts as well as menus or widgets. If you only want to affect the main posts list you need to check $query->is_main_query()

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I'd use this as an accepted solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pre_get_posts` action runs any time posts are queried. This obviously includes the main query for displaying your latest posts or the current page, but it also includes any other time posts are queried. So that would include any use of `WP_Query()` or `get_posts()` in a plugin or your templates, any Recent Posts or similar widgets, and menus (menu items are actually a post type, so any menu on your site will involve a posts query).

If you only want to affect the main query (that being the one you loop over with `have_posts()`, you need to check `$query->is_main_query()`:

```
function wpse_318765_pre_get_posts_callback( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {

    }
}
```